# What is the meaning of unless its called for ?

Tags: meaning

Peter asking by Regina to come in the Regina's house.

> Regina: Won't you come in for a minute?
>
> Peter: No, I won't.
>
> Regina: I don't bite, you know, **unless it's called for**.

**unless it's called for** means *need*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity, what book are you reading?  I met Peter and Regina earlier this evening.

You are correct that `called for` means `needed` (a waitress might "call for" the soup a customer ordered.  The soup is "called for."  Because it was ordered, it is needed.)

However, like in this instance, it is often used in a humorous or sarcastic manner.  In this specific case, it adds a bit of sexual [innuendo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innuendo), which gives the moment a mature, playful feeling.